# [Android][react-native-config] Getting correct .env with productFlavors

Tags: android, react-native, react-native-config

I did as the document with .env file picker like this

```
project.ext.envConfigFiles = [
    debug                  : ".env",
    release                : ".env.production",
    adhoc                  : ".env.test",
    asiaRelease        : ".env.production",
    usRelease           : ".env.production",]
```

And I setup my project with flavors like this

```
flavorDimensions "env"

productFlavors {
    asia_dev {
        dimension "env"
        applicationIdSuffix ".asia.dev"
    }
    asia {
        dimension "env"
        applicationIdSuffix ".asia"
    }
    us_dev {
        dimension "env"
        applicationIdSuffix ".us.dev"
    }
    us {
        dimension "env"
        applicationIdSuffix ".us"
    }
}
```

As I expect when I make build with release, the flavor usRelease and asiaRelease will pick the ".env.production". However, it always picks the ".env" file
Could you guys help me what's going wrong in this case?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Everything is working as expected. The thing is under the hook react-native-config package will create a new .env file from the env you specified during the build time.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35182371)